# Why is touchesCancelled being called after UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: swift

After finally finishing my coding within **touchesBegan**, **touchesMoved**, **touchesEnded**, **touchesCancelled** I started adding code for recognizing taps. I implemented it with the code below.

For some reason after every **UITapGestureRecognizer**, I get a **touchesCancelled**. Did I leave something out, is there a threshold I can modify, or do I somehow have to create my own code that says, I just did a tap, ignore the first cancel that comes along?

So essentially I get a **touchesBegan**, **UITapGestureRecognizer**, followed by a **touchesCancelled**.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

    let tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    ....

    tapRec.addTarget(self, action:#selector(GameScene.tappedView(_:) ))
    tapRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    tapRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)
    ....
}

    @objc func tappedView(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just what a gesture recognizer is / does. When a gesture recognizer recognizes its gesture, the touches for this gesture recognizer are sent to their hit-test views as a `touchesCancelled(_:with:)` message, and then no longer arrive at those views. The gesture recognizer takes over so it signs the view off from its touch sequence in good order.

If you're going to have *both* a gesture recognizer *and* manual touch events, you have to do more work to mediate between them. If you really don't want the standard behavior, you can set the gesture recognizer's `cancelsTouchesInView` property to `false`.